# RQM testNG integration

Tags: testng

How do I integrate testNG with RQM. I have seen articles regarding how to use J Unit adapters for RQM. Will this work for testNG as well?
I am trying to schedule my testNG test from RQM and run it everyday. Any pointers will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was achieved without having to integrate with RQM. Tests were scheduled from Windows task manager and invoked using a batch job